# Timestamp query in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

WHat is the issue with my DATE / Timestamp query?

Please point out.

I am filtering the data based on the date, filter as greater than a timestamp and less than another timestamp.

I tried using :

```
  Select * 
  from TRANSACTION_LOG 
  where DATE_FORMAT(ORIGIN_TIMESTAMP,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') > '" + 
  2018-01-19T11:11+ "' 
  && DATE_FORMAT(ORIGIN_TIMESTAMP,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') < '" + 
  2018-04-01T01:01 +"';
```

AND this one also -->>

```
 Select * 
 from TRANSACTION_LOG 
 where DATE_FORMAT(ORIGIN_TIMESTAMP,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') > '" + 
 2017-01-10T11:52:12.000Z + "' 
 && DATE_FORMAT(ORIGIN_TIMESTAMP,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i') < '" + 
 2018-05-10T11:52:12.000Z +"';
```

neither of them work

Comment: Add sample data and expected output for better answer

Comment: you are adding date in another format

Comment: What is the data type of `ORIGIN_TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 0):

What is the `"+` ?  MySQL should recognize ISO standard formats for date/times.

The following should work in MySQL:

```
Select * 
from TRANSACTION_LOG 
where ORIGIN_TIMESTAMP > '2018-01-19T11:11' and 
      ORIGIN_TIMESTAMP < '2018-04-01T01:01';
```